ionic capacitor error:- ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED | digital envelope routines
I am facing issue on ionic build error after updating to node v18.20.4, It was working fine with node v16.20.2.
I tried below options with no luck
1) set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
Note:- Most of the answers suggesting to downgrade the version but it is not a solution.
   Ionic CLI                     : 7.2.0 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 12.1.1

   Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 6.1.2
   @capacitor/android : 6.1.2
   @capacitor/core    : 6.1.2
   @capacitor/ios     : 6.1.2

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 2.0.1

System:

   NodeJS : v18.20.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 10.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10

Error: on build command
 ionic build
    > ng.cmd run app:build
    - Generating browser application bundles...node:internal/crypto/hash:69
      this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                      ^
    
    Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
        at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
        at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
        at module.exports (F:\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
        at NormalModule._initBuildHash (F:\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
        at F:\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
        at F:\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
        at F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
        at F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:172:11
        at loadLoader (F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:32:11)
        at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
        at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
        at F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
        at loadLoader (F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
        at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
        at runLoaders (F:\app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
        at NormalModule.doBuild (F:\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3) {
      opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
      library: 'digital envelope routines',
      reason: 'unsupported',
      code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
    }


You have to downgrade the node version, please check the below documentation link for compatibility guide.
Version compatibility
Sicne it looks like you are using Angular 11.1.4, then downgrade node to ^10.13.0 || ^12.11.0 ( recommended in docs ) or stay at v16.20.2 (since you are not facing any issues) to resolve this problem.

But I need to update as per google: App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or later

@DeepakDholiyan Does this update require node.js to be updated, both are not related right?

This is available in capacitor 6 and is needs node v18
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/6-0

@DeepakDholiyan Then please upgrade angular first then proceed with upgrading capacitor and node. as per the compatibility link shared in my answer.

ok fine, I will try.
